# error with img selector

Tags: html, css

here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>testing css</h1>
    <p>this text shows the paragrpah going under css</p>
    <img src = "http://images.wikia.com/glee/images/1/1d/ImaFes.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS code

```
h1 {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif , serif;
    color:#576D94;
} 
p {
    font-size:18px;
    color: #4A4943;
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
}
img {
    height=100px;
    width=300px;
    border=1px solid #4682b4;
}
```

the error i found is with img selector. the editor shows an empty rule on img selector line. 
hope i didn't do anything wrong with img selector.

sorry if any grammatical errors

Comment: really sorry... i've seen every step but didn't concentrate on the colon part. thanks and sorry for wasting your valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it yourself.

You are using:

```
img {
height=100px;
width=300px;
border=1px solid #4682b4;
}
```

Which should be:

```
img {
height:100px;
width:300px;
border:1px solid #4682b4;
}
```

Remove the equal signs and it will be something like the above.

Comment: really sorry... i've seen every step but didn't concentrate on the colon part. thanks and sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a colon instead of an equal sign:

```
img {
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid #4682b4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a colon sign missing

```
img {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #4682b4;
}
```

here is a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/AkTDa/)**